# Electric potential at ONE point around an infinite line charge

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, potential

The problem states that you've got two infinite charged wires with linear densities of charge (l and -l) and you must calculate the electric potential at any given point.

I dont know how to do this without using a reference point where V = 0 (which is usually infinity, but not in this case)

Comment: So you choose a convenient reference point where the potential is zero.

Comment: Why not in this case? Is that a restriction by the problem (or instructor)? Also, think about Farcher's question carefully.

Comment: Because we usually assume that the potential is 0 in infinity since by convention there are no charges. But now, there are because the line is infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field due to one infinite line charge is given by 
$$\vec E(r)=\frac{l}{2\pi\epsilon_0 r}\hat r$$

And the potential upon integration of this field is given by
$$V(r)=-\int_{r_0}^r \vec E(\rho)\cdot d\hat\rho=\frac{l}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\log\frac{r_0}{r}$$

Where $V=0$ at $r=r_0$

Now, let's assume the lines in the problem are parallel separated by a distance d, and let's put the positive line on the z-axis. Then the field is given by

$$\vec E=\frac{l}{2\pi\epsilon_0 r}\hat r-\frac{l}{2\pi\epsilon_0 (r-d)}\hat r$$

You can do a similar integration and pick a point $r_0$ where $V=0$ to get the overall potential here. Since this seems like a homework question I will leave the final details to you.

Comment: @V.F. No problem. It was a very convincing answer :) In general you want to perform the integral, then if possible you can put the reference point at infinity. This is where it is important for $E$ to go to $0$ fast enough so that at infinity the integral is not divergent.